# SQL Server Report Builder - Expression to Sort Value to Bottom of Column

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

Is there a way or expression for me to sort a value to the bottom of a list in MS SQL Server Report Builder 3.0? I have a column named Project Names and a value named **"Resource".** There are about 20+ Project Name values. Is there an expression I can use to sort the `field!ProjectName.Value` so that the Project Name **"Resource"** appears at the bottom of the column instead of in the order A to Z? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

How about making a new column SortOrder that has the following expression:

```
IF(field!Projection.Value<>"Resource",field!Projection.Value,"zzzResource")
```

Just make the column invisible on your report.

Comment: Can this be done when the column is grouped? I've created a ProjectSort Column and added the expression but it doesn't seem to be sorting at all. The Project Name field is grouped and is between grouped columns.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than do this in ReportBuilder, I would consider creating a 'sequence' column in the sql that uses:

```
CASE WHEN ProjectName = 'Resource' THEN 0
 ELSE 1
END AS SEQ
```

Then you could sort on the sequence column. `field!SEQ.Value`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish the desired sorting by creating a new column ProjectSort in my dataset where Project Names that = "Resource" was renamed "ZZZZZ". The new column ProjectSort was applied to the Row Group ProjectName via Group Properties > Sorting > Sortby > ProjectSort. Thanks for the idea!